# Когда использовать выравнивание в 1 байт

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>

struct S1
{
    char a;
    int b;
    char d;
};

#pragma pack(1)
struct S2
{
    char a;
    int b;
    char d;
};

int main()
{
 std::cout<<sizeof(S1)<<std::endl;
 std::cout<<sizeof(S2)<<std::endl;
}
```

> output:
>
> 12
>
> 6

Когда стоить использовать выравнивание в 1 байт, только при небольших объемах памяти? Какие плюсы и минусы?

Comment: Когда это нужно для совместимости - с другими программами, API, и т.п.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Пройдемся по плюсам и минусам.

- плюсы

  - структуры имеют меньший размер, меньше расход памяти
  - бывает удобно при сериализации/десериализации
  - иногда упрощает низкоуровневый код.
- минусы

  - внутренние поля могут быть выровненные "неудобно" для процессора и можно получить замедление работы программы
  - иногда выравнивание может быть не таким, как ожидает программист. Может быть разным на разных платформах или версиях компилятора. Поэтому для сериализации иногда может и не подойти. Нужно как минимум жестко контролировать через sizeof и другие методы.
  - выравнивание очень специфично работает, если есть битовые поля (специфично - не так как ожидает программист).

В целом, выравнивание стоит использовать в следующих ситуациях:

- нужно хранить много-много структур и скоростью работы программы можно пожертвовать. Но возможно можно просто переупорядочить поля.
- пишется простое ipc и размер имеет значение (хотя лучше взять что то готовое)
- используется api операционной системы и "так нужно".
- хочется поэкспериментировать и поизучать компилятор глубже.

P.S. Кстати, в коде есть проблема. После того, как применили упаковку, нужно её аккуратно вернуть назад. Да, в этом примере ничего не будет, но если `pragma pack` попадет в header файл, может быть большая беда - одна и та же структура будет иметь разный размер в разных единицах компиляции, поля будут выровнены по разному.

```
#pragma pack(push, 1)
struct Foo
{
    // ...
};
#pragma pack(pop)
```

P.S.S. Можно ещё на [хабре](https://habr.com/post/142662/) почитать.

Answer (score 2):

Когда использовать? Тогда, когда Вы точно знаете, что делаете и это абсолютно необходимо. Какие минусы? Неопределённое поведение. Вот Ваш модифицированный код:

```
#include <iostream>

using std::cout;

struct S1
{
    char a;
    int b;
    char d;
};

#pragma pack(1)
struct S2
{
    char a;
    int b;
    char d;
};

int main()
{
    cout << sizeof(S1) << "\n";
    cout << sizeof(S2) << "\n";
    cout << alignof(int) << "\n";
    S2 s2;
    size_t address = reinterpret_cast<size_t>(&s2.b);
    cout << "Var address: " << std::hex << address  << "\n";
    cout << "Properly aligned? " << std::boolalpha << (address % alignof(int) == 0);
}
```

Последняя строчка скорее всего выведет `false`, что означает, что переменная типа `int` расположена по адресу, который противоречит требования выравнивания для этого типа (стандарт [[basic.align]](http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.align)). А раз это противоречит требованиям стандарта, значит Ваша программа некорректна.